# Gitlab installation timeout

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

When trying to clone the Gitlab repo to my local server running FreeNAS I get the following erfror messages:

Using HTTPS (https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce.git):

```
error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 408
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Using SSH (See: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce):

```
Connection closed by 52.21.36.51
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Has anyone an idea to solve this issue?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly is sometimes caused by network issues.If it doesn't solve it then use this command git config http.postBuffer 524288000 and try again.

Comment: @Golden_flash: Tried your suggested solution of increasing the HTTP timout with the `--global` as well as with the `--system` option. Didn't bring any succcess. :(    Any other ideas?